# Swagger UI is not showing HTTPS scheme and SSL certificate is offloaded (is on Load Balancer)

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, swagger-ui, f5, nswag

My Swagger UI is not showing HTTPS scheme in schemes dropdown. SSL certificate is offloaded on the Load balancer, is there a way that swagger is aware of the SSL certificate and shows HTTPS scheme, or do I have to make any settings on the load balancer?
Already tried the following but it didn't helped:

- https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1545
- [How do I specify the "scheme" element using NSwag and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631990/how-do-i-specify-the-scheme-element-using-nswag-and-c)

Comment: Got it, issue is fixed referring to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631990/how-do-i-specify-the-scheme-element-using-nswag-and-c, I have Nswag version 13, so adding version-specific code fixed the issue.